# Problems in the \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates in fillbetween domain

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}                    
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\InterseccaoX}[1]{
                        \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1} 
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{
                             \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}
                        }
}

\newcommand{\InterseccaoY}[1]{
                        \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1} 
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{
                             \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}
                        }
}

\newcommand{\ValorInterseccao}[1]{
\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1}\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-2:2, samples=100,axis lines=middle,ymin=-0.5,xmin=-3,xmax=3]


  % Desenhe a curva f(x)
  \addplot[name path=f, blue] {exp(-x^2)}; 

  % Desenhe a curva g(x)
  \addplot[name path=g, red] {0.5*x^2};

  % Encontre os pontos de interseção
  \path[name intersections={of=f and g, name=i}];

  \fill (i-1) circle (2pt);
  \fill (i-2) circle (2pt);

  % Preencha a área entre as curvas apenas entre os pontos de interseção
   \node[below=15pt,inner sep=2pt] (Ia) at ($(0,0)!(i-1)!(-1,0)$) {\InterseccaoX{(i-1)}};
   \node[below=15pt,inner sep=2pt] (Ib) at ($(0,0)!(i-2)!(-1,0)$) {\InterseccaoX{(i-2)}};
   \node[below,inner sep=1pt] (Ic) at ($(0,0)!(i-2)!(0,1)$) {\InterseccaoY{(i-2)}};

   \draw[densely dotted] (Ib) -- (i-2) -- (i-1) -- (Ia);
\addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between[of=f and g,soft clip={domain=-0.92:0.92}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

where I have determined the intersections points of this curves.That's ok. But, when I try to fill the area between the curves using the instruction:

```
\addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between[of=f and g,soft clip={domain=-0.92:0.92}];
```

I need to provide the x values of the intersection (`-0.92:0.92`). There is a way to I give a command and the x-intersections be inserted automatically? For example, I have tried:

```
domain=\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(i-1)}\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}:\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(i-2)}\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}
```

but not worked.
Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already load the `fillbetween` library, you can make use of the `intersection segments` option and avoid the separate calculation of the coordinates altogether:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\InterseccaoX}[1]{
    \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}
    }
}

\newcommand{\InterseccaoY}[1]{
    \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2, 
    samples=100,
    axis lines=middle,
    ymin=-0.5, 
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3
]

    % Desenhe a curva f(x)
    \addplot[name path=f, blue] {exp(-x^2)}; 
    
    % Desenhe a curva g(x)
    \addplot[name path=g, red] {0.5*x^2};
    
    % Encontre os pontos de interseção
    \path[name intersections={of=f and g, name=i}];
    
    \fill (i-1) circle (2pt);
    \fill (i-2) circle (2pt);

    % Preencha a área entre as curvas apenas entre os pontos de interseção
    \node[below=15pt, inner sep=2pt] (Ia) at ($(0,0)!(i-1)!(-1,0)$)   
        {\InterseccaoX{(i-1)}};
    \node[below=15pt, inner sep=2pt] (Ib) at ($(0,0)!(i-2)!(-1,0)$) 
        {\InterseccaoX{(i-2)}};
    \node[below, inner sep=1pt] (Ic) at ($(0,0)!(i-2)!(0,1)$) 
        {\InterseccaoY{(i-2)}};
    
    \draw[densely dotted] (Ib) -- (i-2) -- (i-1) -- (Ia);

    \fill[gray, opacity=0.4, intersection segments={
        of=f and g,
        sequence={L2 -- R2[reverse]},
    }] -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another solution could be to not only give a `domain` as `soft path` but an actual path where you can use the precalculated intersection coordinates.

You can make use of the `-|` syntax here. The following code

```
(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin} -| i-1) rectangle 
(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax} -| i-2)
```

in the below example means: Return a rectangle where

- the first coordinate has an *x* value that is the same of coordinate `(i-1)` and a *y* value that is the same as the minimum *y* value of the current plot,
- the second coordinate has an *x* value that is the same of coordinate `(i-2)` and a *y* value that is the same as the maximum *y* value of the current plot.

Using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}` ensures that the resulting area covers the full height of the plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\InterseccaoX}[1]{
    \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}
    }
}

\newcommand{\InterseccaoY}[1]{
    \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{#1} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2, 
    samples=100,
    axis lines=middle,
    ymin=-0.5, 
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3
]

    % Desenhe a curva f(x)
    \addplot[name path=f, blue] {exp(-x^2)}; 
    
    % Desenhe a curva g(x)
    \addplot[name path=g, red] {0.5*x^2};
    
    % Encontre os pontos de interseção
    \path[name intersections={of=f and g, name=i}];
    
    \fill (i-1) circle (2pt);
    \fill (i-2) circle (2pt);

    % Preencha a área entre as curvas apenas entre os pontos de interseção
    \node[below=15pt, inner sep=2pt] (Ia) at ($(0,0)!(i-1)!(-1,0)$)   
        {\InterseccaoX{(i-1)}};
    \node[below=15pt, inner sep=2pt] (Ib) at ($(0,0)!(i-2)!(-1,0)$) 
        {\InterseccaoX{(i-2)}};
    \node[below, inner sep=1pt] (Ic) at ($(0,0)!(i-2)!(0,1)$) 
        {\InterseccaoY{(i-2)}};
    
    \draw[densely dotted] (Ib) -- (i-2) -- (i-1) -- (Ia);

    \addplot[fill=gray, opacity=0.4] 
        fill between[of=f and g, soft clip={
            (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin} -| i-1) rectangle 
            (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax} -| i-2)
        }
    ];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, this solves my problem. But, it is possible obtain the x-intersection from macro:
```\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(i-1)}\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}```

Comment: @ANGELOALIANOFILHO I think you cannot use this approach for further calculations in `\path`s, but I am unsure why that is. You can, however also put a path as `soft path` and use the coordinates directly. See the edit of my answer.